# Most sensible approach to generate repeated HTML source. Use PHP?

Tags: php, html

Hi I was wondering what is a sensible approach to generating repeated HTML source code such as that below. Suppose I have, say, thirty, lines where the numbering goes from 1 to 30, say. And I have a number of such pages that need this structure. I had jumped to generating this code in the page itself using a PHP loop, as I'm using PHP anyway in the project.

My question is, is this a sensible approach? What is best practice in such cases? I'm not sure using PHP in the page to generate the HTML each time like this is wise. Or is it?

Thank you for any steer or advice.

```
<a href="images/mypic (1).jpg">
<img src="images/mypic (1).jpg" alt="Picture 1">
</a>

<a href="images/mypic (2).jpg">
<img src="images/mypic (2).jpg" alt="Picture 2">
</a>

etc..
```

Comment: I see no reason not to use something like PHP for this, programming languages are good at generating repetitive content. Most web-based PHP programs generate HTML content.

Comment: You may also use plain Javascript to dynamically create DOM elements containing the links and images, if PHP is not your preference or not "plain" enough

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was kind of looking for the relative merits of using PHP versus Javascript. Apart from one is back-end and one is client-side, and so there are clear pros and cons there. I wondered what other comparisons there might be.

Answer (score 2):

That's precisely the purpose of PHP : generating HTML code.

You can use a simple for loop :

```html
<?php for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++) : ?>
  <a href="images/mypic (<?= $i ?>).jpg">
    <img src="images/mypic (<?= $i ?>).jpg" alt="Picture <?= $i ?>">
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not JS? That would transfer the least code from the server

```js
document.body.innerHTML = Array.from({length:30})
  .map((_,i) => `<a href="images/mypic%20(${(i+1)}).jpg"><img src="images/mypic%20(${(i+1)}).jpg" alt="Picture ${(i+1)}"></a>`)
  .join('<br/>')
```